# What are Different Bootloaders Available for Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

We are familiar with `GRUB2` which is the next generation of the GRand Unified Bootloader (GRUB). It is the default `bootloader` since 9.10 (Karmic Koala).

It would be good to know about what are other `boot-loaders` available and how to install them in Ubuntu?

Comment: Why there is a downvote? I request to give appropriate reasons so that I could eliminate the mistakes..! What wrong in this question? If you get something wrong please edit it..

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is **BURG** (**B**rand-new **U**niversal loade**R** from **G**RUB). You can set up themes or wallpapers for the bootloader. Here is how you can install it from terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

To update the boot loader:

```
sudo update-burg
```

[image: BURG]

Source: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-burg-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-and-linux-mint-15-14-13/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few bootloaders. Though [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) and [BURG](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Burg) are the most common ones.

There is [LILO(Linux Loader)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_%28boot_loader%29). [Package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lilo) for LILO

There is [Das U-Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot). [Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=u-boot-tools) for Das U-Boot.

There is [Yaboot](http://yaboot.ozlabs.org/) (Yet Another BOOT loader). Generally installed on Mac machines. Here's the [community document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/YabootConfigurationForMacintoshPowerPCsDualBoot)  on Yaboot for Ubuntu.

There is [PALO](http://www.pateam.org/parisc-linux-boot/PA-RISC-Linux-Boot-HOWTO/palo.html). You can get Ubuntu packages for palo [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/palo).

Comment: another good boot loader is Clover  ... Clover EFI is a boot loader developed to boot OS X (Hackintoshes), Windows and Linux in legacy or UEFI mode  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clover