# How to change the header title and help message in GRUB menu?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, menu, tweak

How to change the header title and help message in GRUB menu?

My Grub version is `1.99-21ubuntu3` and I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

[image]

Comment: You can try [BURG](http://askubuntu.com/a/354332/147044).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Thanks i know BURG i do want to edit GRUB

Comment: Try [Grub Customizer](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-grub-customizer-302-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: @Mitch: Grub Customizer is not offering such capability

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to edit the **grub2** source code to modify those strings *(Header,Footer etc).*

---

#### NOTE: I recommend you to do this in a Virtual Machine or in a Test Machine to see is everything is OK. *(In this example I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with grub2 1.99-21ubuntu3.10).*

---

**1)** Make sure you have enable the [Source code repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221899/how-to-download-source-code-with-apt-get).

- Open the Ubuntu Software Center.
- In the Menu Bar choose **Edit -> Software Sources**. Click to enable **"Source code repository"**.
  Just in case I use the **"Main Server"** to Download.

[image]

Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `sudo apt-get update`

**2)** In the Terminal type the following to install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential quilt`

**3)** Install build dependencies.

- `sudo apt-get build-dep grub2`

**4)** Create a folder to download the source code.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src`

**5)** Download the source code & Export variables.

- `apt-get source grub2`
- `export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches`
- `export EDITOR=gedit`

**6)** Create the patch and edit the source code.

- `cd grub2-1.99`
- `quilt new 99_custom-header-footer.patch`

---

#### Edit the main.c file

- `quilt edit grub-core/normal/main.c`

[image]

**As an example I changed the line 214**

**From:**

```
  const char *msg = _("GNU GRUB  version %s");
```

**To:**

```
  const char *msg = _("My Custon Grub Title");
```

---

#### Edit the menu_text.c file

- `quilt edit grub-core/normal/menu_text.c`

Edit the "Strings" (Pink Color) According to your needs.

[image]

**Only as an example I changed the lines 159 & 160**

**From:**

```
  const char *msg = _("Use the %C and %C keys to select which "
          "entry is highlighted.\n");
```

**To:**

```
      const char *msg = _("You can write a text message here according \
to your needs...\n");
```

**And the lines 187 to 189**

**From:**

```
(_("Press enter to boot the selected OS, "
   "\'e\' to edit the commands before booting "
   "or \'c\' for a command-line.\n"),
```

**To:**

```
        (_("You can put a message here... to press \
a key to boot the OS.\nOr a Help text... etc."),
```

---

**7)** Build the deb packages.

- `quilt refresh`
- `fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage`

*NOTE: This may take awhile.*

**8)** Install the deb packages.

- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i grub-pc*.deb grub2-common*.deb`

**9)** Finally you can Restart your machine to see the changes.

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks im going to try it then il reply you and mark answer if done

Comment: How to replace the old grub with the new?

Comment: @maythux when you compile, create the deb package & then install with dpkg -i... this new grub should replace the old grub, just restart you machine.

Comment: Great man :) you deserve

Answer (score 0):

you can use a .\locales\en.mo file to change the menu heading.
One example is [here](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/142---windows-restore-uefi#TOC-Change-the-grub2-menu-heading)